# Can a Windows Azure Mobile Service accept GET requests from any domain?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I have a PhoneGap App running on WP7 that I would like to connect to a Windows Azure Mobile Service. However, in order for this to work in my testing using JSFiddle.net I had to add the JSFiddle domain to the CORS settings in the Windows Azure Mobile Service.

Why do I need to add domains to the CORS setting on the server when doing a simple GET?
Since the Mobile Service requires a key from the JavaScript code I don't see why I cannot open up this web service to any request that supplies the correct key but adding *.* does not seem to work. If this worked I could move on to testing the scenario on the Phone.

Am I missing something architecturally here or is this just a feature that no-one else is looking for?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow any domain to access your mobile service, you can add the `*` in the list of cross-origin resource sharing hostnames under the `configure` tab.

Notice that the application key is not secure. From the '[How to use an HTML/JavaScript client for Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/how-to-guides/work-with-html-js-client/)' tutorial (*emphasis mine*):

> **Application key**: A unique value that is generated by Mobile Services, distributed with your app, and presented in client-generated requests. While useful for limiting access to your mobile service from random clients, *this key is not secure and should not be used to authenticate users of your app*.

The takeaway is that you should not count on that key to secure your service.